# Tagging for recommendations

Tags: discussion, tagging

There's already been [some discussion](http://meta.audio.stackexchange.com/q/20/64) on whether recommendation questions should be allowed.  I don't think a conclusion has been reached, but there seems to be tentative support for these questions as long as they are specific and relevant.  I think [this question](http://audio.stackexchange.com/q/312/64) is a good example.

So, assuming some recommendation questions are allowed to remain on the site, how should they be tagged?

- StackOverflow has a [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) tag
- WebApps has `*-rec` tags for software, webapps, and other categories
- SuperUser has [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec), [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec), [product-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/product-rec), and https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/service-rec

Any thoughts on how we should tag these question here on ARP?

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a situation where someone'd want to categorize for hardware recommendations versus software recommendations.  If I'm looking for a recommendation, I'm going to already have an idea of what category that's in (maybe I'm looking for a particular effect, or I'm soliciting advice on a topic) which will already be more specific and taggable.

Really, I don't see a lot of utility for a recommendation tag of any sort, but I could imagine that someone might want to use it, say, to filter out more subjective questions.

I'd vote for just having the single recommendation tag.